# LINQ - sort on multiple columns

Tags: linq, sorting, multiple-columns

I have a collection with the values below:

```
ID | OtherId
1    0
2    0
3    1
3    2
3    3
4    1
4    2
4    3
5    0
6    0
```

Is there a way to get the output in the below sorted way using LINQ?

```
ID | OtherId
1    0
2    0
3    1
4    1
3    2
4    2
3    3
4    3
5    0
6    0
```

Comment: use **orderby** clause

Comment: I doubt the expected result is at all an ordered list? If yes, why [5 0] & [6 0] should not follow [1 0 ] & [2 0] pairs Or it should be first column sort first, isn't it?

Comment: You need to explain what the rules are. As it currently stands, your question is unanswerable because you haven't given us enough information to say what the sorting criteria are.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use OrderBy and ThenBy:

I haven't tried this, but because your last 2 rows are "out of order" you'll need to first order by (not) specific values, then by columns. It'll be something like this:

```
var sorted = table
             .Where(x => x.SomeColumn == someValue)
             .OrderBy(x => x.ID != 5)
             .ThenBy(x => x.ID != 6)
             .ThenBy(x => x.OtherId)
             .ThenBy(x => x.ID)
             .ToList();
```

If you don't want to sort by specific values, you'll need to do 2 queries and union:

```
var valueAtWhichSortingLogicChanges = 4;
var sorted = table
             .Where(x => x.ID <= valueAtWhichSortingLogicChanges)
             .OrderBy(x => x.OtherId)
             .ThenBy(x => x.ID)
             .ToList();

sorted.AddRange(table
             .Where(x => x.ID > valueAtWhichSortingLogicChanges)
             .OrderBy(x => x.OtherId)
             .ThenBy(x => x.ID)
             .ToList());
```

Comment: This will sort by "OtherId" first and then by "Id".  This does not give the expected result. Since I need sorted list based on both columns. See output list.

Comment: Is there a way to achieve this without hard coding any values? Because my collection will have random values.Above one is just an sample one to understand the issue.

Comment: @Rakshith, I'm not sure you understand why your sorting can't be done without hard coding. There is no logical sort that would say "sort by the second column then by the first column unless the first column is greater than 4. Then put those at the end and sort by the second column followed by the first." Does that make sense?

Comment: @Rakshith even more helpful would be the exact logic for sorting the values this way... From your example, it seems completely arbitrary.